# Swap image using setInterval() with class – p5.js

Tags: javascript, class, setinterval, p5.js

I'm working on a project on p5.js

My goal is to swap image every X seconds as I did in this example [here](https://editor.p5js.org/shannon/sketches/ryqmclV1E).

The problem is that when [I try to do the same with a class object](https://editor.p5js.org/shannon/sketches/B1xBMt8yV), setInterval() doesn't work anymore.

Is it something that has to do with scope maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with a simpler example:

```
class Test {
  constructor(testMessage) {
    this.testMessage = testMessage;
  }
  show() {
    println(this.testMessage);
  }
}
```

What would you expect to happen with this code?

```
var message = 'hello';
var test = new Test(message);
message = 'goodbye';
test.show();
```

The way your code works now, it looks like you would expect this to print `'goodbye'`, but in reality this will print `'hello'`.

This is because you're passing in the **value** of the variable into the `Test` constructor. You now have two variables pointing to the same `'hello'` value. You then modify the first variable, **but that doesn't automatically change the value of the second variable**.

To fix this, you could just use a single global `message` variable, something like this:

```
class Test {
  show() {
    println(message);
  }
}

var message = 'testing';
var test = new Test();
test.show();
```

Or you could create something like a `setMessage()` function that allowed you to change the value inside the class:

```
class Test {
  constructor(testMessage) {
    this.testMessage = testMessage;
  }
  show() {
    println(this.testMessage);
  }
  setMessage(testMessage) {
    this.testMessage = testMessage;
  }
}
```